# GluonClient data loss when saving list locally

Tags: java, gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to persist data locally using the `GluonClient`. It is sporadically working for a few elements but throws errors for most.

I initialize by:

```
GluonClient localClient = GluonClientBuilder.create()
    .operationMode(OperationMode.LOCAL_ONLY)
    .build();
```

I'm using a `RestClient` to retreive data from a REST API. Once the list initializes I attempt to save the data locally (attempted using GluonClient for this read with no success):

```
RestClient apiClient = RestClient.create().method("GET")
    .host("http://localhost:8080/api")
    .path("/path/to/data")
    .queryParam("token","mytoken");
JobsIterableInputConverter<Job> converter = new JobsIterableInputConverter<>(Job.class);
GluonObservableList<Job.class> jobs = (DataProvider.retrieveList(apiClient.createListDataReader(converter)));
jobs.initializedProperty((obv,ov,nv)->{
    saveJobList(jobs);
});


private void saveJobListLocally(GluonObservableList<Job> list){
    GluonObservableList<Job> eqs = DataProvider.retrieveList(gluonClient.createListDataReader("jobs", Job.class));
    eqs.initializedProperty().addListener((obv, ov, nv) -> {
        if (nv && eqs.isEmpty()) {
            eqs.addAll(list);
        }
    });
}
```

**This works for some of the data some of the time**, about 4 *(not always 4)* Job objects of 168 get saved and the rest generate the exception:

```
javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Invalid token=EOF at (line no=1, column no=0, offset=-1). Expected tokens are: [CURLYOPEN, SQUAREOPEN]
```

To retrieve the local data, I call:

```
jobs = DataProvider.retrieveList(gluonClient.createListDataReader("jobs", Job.class));
```

and this works fine.

-I can access and use the ~4 objects that get saved but the rest are lost.

-The ~4 objects that do get saved are not the same from one test to the next (most confusing part).

-Data in each job object was made identical to test if data was invalid or if there were invalid characters but saw same issue. Have previously parsed and used data in other applications using `org.json`.

-**Occasionally** files are generated for each 'lost' object with the UID as the file name in addition to the jobs file.

-Twice I saw no exceptions thrown but most data was still missing.

-Job Class uses `IntegerProperty` and `StringProperty` for data types. Getters annotated with `@XMLElement`

The behavior I am seeing from the `GluonClient` is inconsistent.

I tried to use `FileClient` but it does not work with a list (should I be on this track?).

How do I use the `GluonClient` to save and handle local content as a list?

Using `javafxportsVersion= '8.60.7'`

```
public class JobsIterableInputConverter<E> extends InputStreamIterableInputConverter<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    private JsonArray jsonArray = null;
    private int index;
    private final JsonConverter<E> converter;

    public JobsIterableInputConverter(Class<E> targetClass)
    {
        converter = new JsonConverter<>(targetClass);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        if (jsonArray == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return index < jsonArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public E next()
    {
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJsonObject(index++);
        return converter.readFromJson(jsonObject);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator()
    {
        index = 0;

        try (JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(getInputStream())) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = reader.readObject();
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJsonArray("jobs");
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

API Return Format:

```
{"jobs":[
    {"id":0},
    {"id":1}
]}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error message when I try to delete an `FireBase`object with the `Gluon RestClient`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537358/how-to-delete-objects-with-gluon-connect-restclient. Though I don't think the reason is related to your issue. In my case it seems like the exception is caused by the returned json object being null. The glassfish `JsonParserImpl` interprets `null` as `JsonToken.EOF` and throws the exception. (Could you post the code for JobsIterableInputConverter?)

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but does `Job` overwrite `equals` ?

Comment: @jns we may both be seeing the same issue. I am not overwriting equals in the Job class. I've editied my question to include the JobsIterableInputConverter..   If I use the RestClient to access the API and then add objects not already present in the file, I begin to build a complete set... All the data has been processed from the endpoint and added to the file but it took more than 25 iterations to do it,.. accessing the file and adding elements not already in it... each iteration only added 3 or 4 elements before exceptions began... then I would do it again and a few more would be added.

Comment: Since `GluonObservableListImpl` uses a HashMap to store the elements it tracks for changes, I think you should make `Job` overwrite `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was indeed a bug that manifested itself when storing many items from a list to local storage. The reason of the JSON becoming corrupt is that there was possible simultaneous access to the local file in which the objects are stored. The bug has already been fixed with the following pull request: https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/gluon-connect/pull-requests/1/make-sure-there-is-no-simultaneous-access/diff

A new release is planned somewhere during this week.

Comment: Thanks Joeri! connect-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT works like a charm!

Comment: You can use version 1.0.1 if you prefer depending on a released version.